# Tumblr Photoset

Tags: jquery, tumblr

i'm trying to hack my way into the tumblr photoset and i think i located a fix for the max 700 display size.

Let's say that this is the normal iframe that is generated by {Photoset-700}:

```
<iframe class="photoset" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="1048" width="700" style="border:0px; background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" src="http://www.georgefratila.ro/post/20314734048/photoset_iframe/esssk/tumblr_m1tp5634Si1qzc7t7/700/false"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to change the width of the iframe, change the last part of the src url and mantain aspect ratio when enlarged?

width="700" **change this value to 860**
src="http://www.georgefratila.ro/post/20314734048/photoset_iframe/esssk/tumblr_m1tp5634Si1qzc7t7/700/false" **change the last part of the src /700/false into /860/false**

I think i saw it made with jquery on a site but i dont remember the name, i'll look into my history maybe i'll find it.

Thanks for the help.

Edit.1
I think i sorted almost everything:

```
        $('iframe.photoset').each(function() {
      $(this).attr("width", function(index, old) {
            return old.replace("700", "860");
      });
      $(this).attr("src", function(index, old) {
            return old.replace("/700/false", "/860/false");
      });
});
```

The only problem i have now is the height, it doesnt scale to fit the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to come up a lot. I've developed a jQuery plugin that makes Tumblr Photosets completely responsive and can go up to any width you set the container to be. https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset

I prefer this to fiddling around with iFrame sizes since you get more information (includes EXIF data) and really gives you full control over the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem and here it is:

```
//This will change the source address and display the correct size.

        $(".photoset").each(function() { 
    var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace('700','860');
    $(this).attr("src", newSrc);       
}); 
//This will get the new size of the iframe and resize the iframe holder accordingly.

$(function(){
var iFrames = $('.photoset');
function iResize() {
    for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
        iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
    }

    if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 
        iFrames.load(function(){
            setTimeout(iResize, 0); 
        });

        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
            var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
            iFrames[i].src = '';
            iFrames[i].src = iSource;
        }
    } else {
        iFrames.load(function() {
            this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
        });
    }
});
```

If you have any ideas on how to minimise or improve the script please post it below. Enjoy